# Book about a robot in a spaceship that wakes up with the ship failing after having gone through meteoroid rain

Tags: story-identification, books, robots

The scene that I can remember is the following:

A robot/human (not sure) wake up after a lot of time in his spaceship due to an alarm.
He went to the control room and started to check all the systems.
The first system was failing, the second too and also the rest of them.
He was wondering how it could happen and he discovered that he went through a meteoroid shower which destroyed the ship.

---

I thought it was *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* but I think it is not. Or it may be from Isaac Asimov. Maybe from his book of short stories?

Comment: [It does sound somewhat like the aliens who landed on Rupert in "Mostly Harmless" from the "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" series by Douglas Adams.](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Rupert)  If that's it, feel free to make an aswer of it.

Comment: @JRE You nailed it. I have just read the part you told me on Mostly Harmless and it is what i was looking for.

Comment: Well then, make an answer of it.

Answer (score 3):

"Mostly Harmless" from the "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" series by Douglas Adams.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Grebulons):

> During the centuries-long spaceflight the Grebulons were all in suspended animation with their memories saved to the ship's computer (which was struck by an asteroid influenced by Guide Mark II). With the loss of the backup, after the robots carrying it also fell out of the hole made by the asteroid, the Grebulons awoke with no idea where they were going or who they were. What little instructions they could extract from the wrecked computer told them to "land" somewhere and "monitor" something, so they landed on Rupert and monitored the television transmissions from Earth.

- Thanks to [JRE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44649/jre)

Comment: Can you cite the matching bit?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it is the same part. Thank you!